# is it possible to remove one user DatabaseReference when user disconnect

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

While I use .onDisconnect() I tried to then use remove() to delete a DatabaseReference, to remove the user from waiting room from database,

here is my code example:

```
lastOnlineRef
    .onDisconnect()
    .set(ServerValue.timestamp)
    .then(firebaseController.removeThisRoom());
```

but it seems after onDisconnect() nothing can be sent to the server, do we have a better solution for this? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onDisconnect` handler (`set(ServerValue.timestamp)`) runs when the client is no longer connected to the server, so there is no way for the server to notify the client at that point that it has completed the write operation.